# I accidentally deleted opt/psa/admin/conf/php.ini file

Tags: php, ubuntu, plesk

I accidentally removed the php.ini file and now I don't know how to recover it back. Any solutions?

My Ubuntu version is **Ubuntu** 20.04 x86_64 and my **Plesk** version is Plesk Obsidian 18.0.40.1

Comment: As nobody knows what you've stored in that file: have a look at the last backup you've took, or reinitialize it

Comment: How do I reinitialize it? Nothing was modified. It was just there by default I think. I installed everything fresh.

Comment: That depends on how you've installed in in the first place

Comment: Backup your original PHP installation, then re-install it from its original installation files. If you did not not install it yourself, you may need to search the Web to find out how to install PHP on your machine. A fresh installation should give you a fresh php.ini file.     Alternatively, you can beg somebody with a similar set up as yours to email you their php.ini file, which you can put in place then customize as necessary. After you get it back, **don't forget to set up a backup schedule.**